# Фильтрация LINQ to NHibernate с множеством nullable параметров

Tags: c#, orm, linq, nhibernate

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как мне отфильтровать коллекцию объектов, 
когда параметров фильтрации может быть больше 10 и надо проверять их на содержание
значений (все параметры nullable)? Пробовал с ICriteria цепочкой проверки и добавления Restrictions. Но мне не нравятся magic strings и нужно получить в одном случае доступ к внутреннему полю класса. К примеру, метод

```
public string(int? firstParam, int? secondParam, int? thirdParam, int? fourthParam, int? fiveParam, int? sixthParam, int? seventhParam, DateTime? time)
{
    var session = DbSession.JoinOrOpen();

    var collection = session.Linq<ObjectWithManySettings>()... // Либо через лямбда методы 
    collection = from item in session.Linq<ObjectWithManySettins> 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно зачем такие сложности.

Если нужно сделать запрос к таблице БД, отфильтровав его по некоторым столбцам, то это легко делается с помощью лямбда-выражений.

Nhibernate как и все ORM поддерживает постороение запросов через `IQueryable<T>` интерфейс.

Т.е. если DB-entity имеет следующий вид :

```
public class SomeEntity {
    public int Price {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public bool IsDeleted {get; set;} }
```

То с использованием Nhibernate Session класса и метода `Query<T>`

Запрос может выглядеть, например, так:

```
session.Query<SomeEntity>().Where(x=> x.Price = 3 && x.IsDeleted).Select(x=>x.Name);
```

для поиска всех имен энтитей, имеющих цену = 3 и флаг удаления.

Также можно строить join'ы таблиц и использовать SQL-подобныйы синтаксис для построения запросов

Если смущает именно количество аргументов, которые часто повторяются, то можно сделать спецификацию, например используя LinqSpecs (лучше сделать свою реализацию, просто сохраняя Expression)

```
public class SomeSpec: Specification<SomeEntity>
    {
        private int count;
        private bool isDeleted;

        public SomeSpec(int count, bool isDeleted)
        {
            this.count= count;
            this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
        }

        public override Expression<Func<SomeEntity, bool>> IsSatisfiedBy()
        {
            return x => x.Price == price && x.IsDeleted == isDeleted;
        }
    }
```

И использовать уже спецификацию в фильтрации, типа

```
session.Query<SomeEntity>()
  .Where(new SomeSpec(3, true).IsSatisfied())
  .Select(x=>x.Name);
```

Comment: Не совсем то =))
Можно конечно создать энтити но дело в том что мы не имеем значений по умолчанию, поэтому переменные nullable 
На критериях легко построить длинные условия на проверку и убирать лишние или вообще не фильтровать если все значения !value.HasValue 
А Вот на LINQ мне кажется нельзя построить запрос который одновременно проверяет значения на не null и только после этого включать его в фильтр
Вчера весь вечер промучился так и не получилось ничего реализовать